# While compiling the meep c++ code with mpi I get the following error on screen

Tags: c++, mpi, meep

```
root@ubuntutemplti386:~# mpicxx `pkg-config --cflags meep_openmpi` port12.cpp -o port12 `pkg-config --libs meep_openmpi`
/usr/lib/libmpich.so: undefined reference to `MPL_trid'
/usr/lib/libmpich.so: undefined reference to `MPL_trvalid'
/usr/lib/libmpich.so: undefined reference to `MPL_env2int'
/usr/lib/libmpich.so: undefined reference to `MPL_trrealloc'
/usr/lib/libmpich.so: undefined reference to `MPL_trspace'
/usr/lib/libmpich.so: undefined reference to `MPL_trDebugLevel'
/usr/lib/libmpich.so: undefined reference to `MPL_TrSetMaxMem'
/usr/lib/libmpich.so: undefined reference to `MPL_trlevel'
/usr/lib/libmpich.so: undefined reference to `MPL_trmalloc'
/usr/lib/libmpich.so: undefined reference to `MPL_putenv'
/usr/lib/libmpich.so: undefined reference to `MPL_env2bool'
/usr/lib/libmpich.so: undefined reference to `MPL_env2range'
/usr/lib/libmpich.so: undefined reference to `MPL_trcalloc'
/usr/lib/libmpich.so: undefined reference to `MPL_trfree'
/usr/lib/libmpich.so: undefined reference to `MPL_env2str'
/usr/lib/libmpich.so: undefined reference to `MPL_trstrdup'
/usr/lib/libmpich.so: undefined reference to `MPL_trdump'
/usr/lib/libmpich.so: undefined reference to `MPL_trinit'
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you might be trying to combine an Open MPI installation with an MPICH installation. You need to pick one and stick with it.